# Curl requests from inside docker container trigger Captcha at Amazon Login Page

Tags: docker, http, curl, captcha

I want to use [Lötzimmer's Alexa Remote Control](https://loetzimmer.de/patches/alexa_remote_control.sh) shell script inside a docker container to trigger TTS events in my Alexa.

This script basically mimics a user by curling the Amazon Alexa page, logging in and dispatching the TTS event all from the shell. If I execute the script on my PC or my Raspberry Pi, everything works fine. However, I want to embed this script in a docker container and enrich it with further functionality later. So I just created a basic docker image for demonstration purposes:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install curl jq oathtool -y
COPY alexa_remote_control.sh ./
RUN ./alexa_remote_control.sh -d ALL -e speak:'Hi'
```

(Curl and jq are required for the web requests and oathtool is required to generate OTPs from the MFA-secret.)

Now the problem is that when the image is executed, it fails, because Amazon Alexa login page demands a Captcha input.

My guess is that they somehow detect that the request is coming from within a docker container and therefore request a Captcha for spam protection. Are they able to do that and is there any kind of workaround (e.g. by modifying header fields) to prevent this behavior?
Once again: The script is working fine on both my PC and my RPI, but once it is executed from within a docker container, a Captcha is requested.

Thanks in advance!